# How to add new line after bash command before output

Tags: macos, bash

I have my prompt set to add a new line after any preceding output, but I would like to add a new line *before* the output as well (after commands), effectively surrounding my prompt with empty lines for readability.

Currently I have this:

```
{end of previous output}

[~/Documents/scripts]
>>> stroop: echo sample output
sample output
```

This is what I would like to accomplish:

```
{end of previous output}

[~/Documents/scripts]
>>> stroop: echo sample output

sample output
```

Is there a way to do this by modifying PS1 or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding `PROMPT_COMMAND=echo` to your .bashrc? This will execute "echo" after each command.

Or you can use something like `trap echo DEBUG` to intercept the execution and strike that echo before each command.

This works for me:

```
bash-3.2$ cat .bashrc

trap echo DEBUG
bash-3.2$ cd foo/

bash-3.2$ ls

foo
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: I'm using .bash_profile to export my PS1 (on mac) and this didn't do anything. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Try executing the command directly in your shell to see if it does something first

Comment: Oh, well I missed a letter. It adds an additional new line *after* the output, though. Not before.

Comment: `trap echo debug` works, but it does add about 7 new lines before my prompt when I first launch a terminal window.

Comment: The DEBUG trap runs before every "simple command", so if your command is a pipe (`grep pat file | wc`), you'll get a blank line for each pipe component.